# Establish mutual tls connection between pods in openshift

Tags: openshift

How can i establish tls connection in two pods in openshift

pods are in same cluster

my application limitation is i cannot use service mesh for this purpose
is there any another to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Usually pods in the same cluster would not need to protect from each other. If you do need to isolate an application and secure access to it, you could probably have it in a separate project and secure the route created for the service. Then access the service using the route.